# Model Default Order By

Tags: php, yii

I would like to make a model default be `order by` in all finds.
In relation, I can declare default `order by`, there is any way to declare a default `order by` for a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array(
            'order'=>$this->getTableAlias(false, false).'.fieldname DESC',
    );
}
```

Yii Manual: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar